# How to add a system privilege to allow to alter jobs from another schema in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, privileges

I have dbms_scheduler jobs in an oracle  database (11.2) in a schema (schema1), I would like to grant a system privilege to alter jobs from another schema (schema2) to schema1. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not an easy way to grant privileges for all objects in another schema. But [you have two other options](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/schedadmin.htm#i1011204) I can think of:

1. `GRANT ALTER myjob1 TO schema1;` - you can grant schema1 alter privileges for individual jobs in schema2.
2. `GRANT SCHEDULER_ADMIN TO schema1;` - this is a powerful DBA privilege allowing schema1 to create/alter any scheduler job (which allows them to execute code as any other user).

I would recommend option 1.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the two options mentioned by @kfinity, there is the third option of creating a PL/SQL stored procedure in `schema2` that changes it's own jobs (just a wrapper around calls to `DBMS_SCHEDULER`), and then grant execute on this procedure to `schema1`.